# Is there a recommended type of can for building a penny stove?

Tags: stoves, alcohol

Related to this [question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/19783/when-building-a-penny-stove-how-do-you-keep-the-cans-from-splitting), I have had better luck with the smaller energy drink/V8 juice cans than standard 12 oz pop cans. The other [question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/10363/what-is-the-most-efficient-diy-alcohol-stove-for-narrow-pots/10421#10421) on the site mentions both beer and Redbull cans.

Is there a **recommended type of can for building a penny stove?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The all time best for my money has been the [12oz Heineken Keg Can](http://www.totalwine.com/beer/lager/euro-pale-lager/heineken/p/3380123?s=1606&igrules=true). If cut correctly, the parts are much easier to slide together securely. Unfortunately, these cans can be pretty difficult to get a hold of these days, as mostly regular straight sided cans are distributed now.
If you can get them, instructions [here](http://www.roguehangar.com/hunt/CampList/AlcoholStoves/PennyStove/Penny%20Ultralight%20Alcohol%20Backpacking%20Stove%20web%20site%20archive/stoveinstruct.html).

[image: 12oz Heineken Keg Can]

The second best I've experienced, while not a penny stove (still alcohol burning) is the style made from a [cheap aluminum water bottle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dDMJs0lvlNw), much easier to work with than flimsy soda cans.

[image: Bottle stove]

Answer (score 3):

While not a traditional penny stove, I built [Tetkoba's Capillary Hoop Stove](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fbHHQrh9m58) out of 3 cans of Red Bull like he did. It took a lot of force to push the hoop inside the main body, but it never split. It's quite sturdy fully assembled, so the Red Bull cans get my approval.